# A faster Serializer for AvalonDock 2.0

Tags: serialization, avalondock

The built in Xml serializer is super slow so I'm looking for a faster one, cant anyone that made one so I'm looking at making one myself.

I havent been able to find a seriaizer that works with the LayoutRoot object, I tried

http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

But it gives me a casting error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Policy.Zone' to type
>   'System.Security.Policy.Url'.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Sorry no, but it did get a bit faster when Xceed took over (AvalonDock 2.0.2).

Comment: See https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/288